# Python - Best way to recursively create a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None      

sum = 25
  ans = []
  def recurse(s, traverse, ls):
                #append tuple
                ls = ls + (traverse.val,)
                if (traverse.right):
                    recurse(s, traverse.right, ls)
                if (traverse.left):
                    recurse(s, traverse.left, ls)
                if (s==sum): 
                    #convert touple and add to answer
                    tmp = list(ls)
                    ans.append(tmp)

  a = tuple()
  recurse(0, root, a)
```

In this code I am dynamically appending lists to a list (ans). In this example, I am using recursion and using tuples to build every sublist because it is immutable. Then, I convert it to a list and append it to my answer. If I were to only use lists, I would not be able to pass copies each time my function is called.

Are there any performance downsides to using tuples this way? Is there a better way to recursively create a list for similar problems?

Also, this method would not really work with a 2d list... Whats the best way to make a 2D immutable list?

Comment: You should use `if traverse.right is not None:` rather than `if (traverse.right):`

Comment: Is there a reason for this?

Comment: If you call `if object` where `object` is some instance of a class, it will call its `__bool__` or `__nonzero__` method if it exists (depending on the python version). So it is ambiguous if `if var` is checking the return value of some objects `__bool__`/`__nonzero__` method of if `var` is None. `if object is None` however only ever explicitly checks if the identity of the variable is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `sum` is the max numbers of traversal you want to do.

The following will do the trick:

```
def traverse(root, limit=None, count=0):
    if not root or count == limit:
        return []
    traversal = [root.val]
    traversal += traverse(root.right, limit, count + len(traversal))
    traversal += traverse(root.left, limit, count + len(traversal))
    return traversal
```

Then, you'd just call it like this:

```
root = TreeNode(20)
root.right = TreeNode(40)
root.right.right = TreeNode(50)
root.right.left = TreeNode(30)
root.left = TreeNode(10)
root.left.left = TreeNode(5)

traverse(root)          // [20, 40, 50, 30, 10, 5]
traverse(root, limit=1) // [20]
traverse(root, limit=4) // [20, 40, 50, 30]
```

---

Or if you can provide the `right` and `left` nodes at `__init__`, you can take a cool functional style approach:

```
print(
    traverse(
        Node(20,
            right=Node(40,
                right=Node(50),
                left=Node(30)),
            left=Node(10,
                left=Node(5))),
        limit=3))
 # > [20, 40, 50]
```